# Limits on the information obtained through optical measurements

Tags: optics, laser, measurements, interference, thought-experiment

Consider a *Gedankenexperiment* shown in the figure below. 
[image: Indistinguishability of two different optical sources]
There are two lasers $S1$ and $S2$ with exactly the same specifications on paper. In practice, they are of course somewhat different but their characteristics can be slightly tuned in all degrees of freedom (DOFs) of interest. To elaborate, by changing the operating conditions such as currents, temperature, cavity lengths, etc., one can influence the output power, wavelength, state of polarization, etc.

The output of $S1$ is fed into a black box that contains state-of-the-art optical and optoelectronic elements, such as wave plates, beam splitters, gratings, phase lockers, photo detectors, etc. [Basically, the richest optical lab you can find in the galaxy ;-)] The properties of the light beam from $S1$ are measured -- detected and analyzed -- as thoroughly as possible and based on the information obtained, the output of $S2$ is tuned so that its characteristics mimic those of $S1$ to the best extent possible. For example, using appropriate combinations of waveplates and polarizers, it should be possible to manipulate the state of polarization.

From the black box, two beams $Sa$ and $Sb$ emerge; one being just the split-off version of the original beam $S1$ while the other is the tuned output of $S2$. *But which one is which is unknown to any outsider*.

**Can beams $Sa$ and $Sb$ be made fundamentally indistinguishable? And if so, only on classical level or on quantum level too?** For instance, would classically interfering them lead to fringes with an almost perfect contract (Visibility $\approx 1$) yet some quantum-optical measurement succeeds in revealing the origin of $Sa$ and $Sb$ correctly to the outsider? If so, what kind of measurement would this be?

Some more assumptions to avoid confusion:

1. The splitting ratio of $S1$ is also controlled inside the box.
2. The measurement procedure in the black box needn't be instantaneous, i.e., a reasonable amount of time (mins, hours, days...) for precise characterization of $S1$ and adapting the control of $S2$ is allowed.
3. Outputs of $S1$ and $S2$ are bright enough to be described classically, i.e. a quantum-mechanical description may not be necessary. Also, beam $S1$ is not actively transformed/modulated in any manner in its entire path. This is to basically state that the no-cloning theorem does not apply since 1) the state is classical, and 2) also known.
4. The characteristics of the laser sources can indeed be controlled quite well (i.e., one doesn't need to think about sources at very exotic wavelengths or with very special output spatial profiles -- basically, all properties the measurement of which have been mastered quite well by the modern laser technology).

Comment: Atoms are indistinguishable and that is true for atoms in a laser, just as well. Beyond that it is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: $S1$ and $S2$ are as such different lasers so in practice, they can of course be distinguished, e.g., their central wavelengths may differ by a few kHz. I am trying to ask if the information obtained through measuring them could prove sufficient enough to render them indistinguishable with the proposed gedankenexpt. And if so, is this indistinguishability just classical in nature? Or does it exist on the quantum level too?

Comment: Can one distinguish two large chunks of matter? Yes. Do they have to be lasers? No. Can one make the light from multiple lasers indistinguishable by entangling the states of their atoms? Yes. So your answer is: it depends. So what did you learn today?